# Can I use a validation function to output error messages within a span id tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", mouseOver1);

function mouseOver1(){

   document.getElementById("button1").style.color = "red";

}


document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", mouseOver); 


    function mouseOver(){ 

      document.getElementById("button2").style.color = "purple";
   }



$("#button1").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
}); 

$("#button2").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
}); 
 

 $('#button1').on('click', function () {
   var error = 0; 
   var usernameError = document.getElementById("username_error1");
   var passwordError = document.getElementById("password_error2");

   if ($(".existingUsername").get(0).value != "S0104675") {
   usernameError.innerHTML = "Please enter an existing valid username";
    error = 1; 
    } else {
    usernameError.innerHTML = '';
   } 
   if ($(".existingPassword").get(0).value != "honor433") {
    passwordError.innerHTML = "Please enter an existing valid password";
     error = 1;

   } else {
    passwordError.innerHTML = '';
  }
  if(error == 0)
  {  
     $("#para1").animate({ left: "-100%" });
     $(".username-label").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $(".existingUsername").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $(".password-label").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $(".existingPassword").animate({ left: "-105%" });
     $("#button1").animate({ left: "-105%" });
  }

});

$('#button2').validate(function() {
          var rules= {
           newUsername: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    }, 
                    newPassword: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    }, 
                       newEmail:{
                        regex: "/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+ @[A-Za-z0-9]+ [A-Za-z0-9]"
                    }, 
                       repeatEmail: {
                         ".newEmail"
                    },
            
               },

             var messages= { 
                 newUsername: "Username must be at least 6 characters", 
                 newPassword: "Password must be at least 6 characters",  
                 newEmail: "Email must be a value and contain "@" " 
                 repeatEmail: { 
                       required: "Email must match EmailAddress",
                       required: "Email must have a value",
                    }, 
               }
          
            });
```

```css
.intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Cambria';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.intro p {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font: italic;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0px 690px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#para1 {
  padding: 0px 1050px 0px 20px;
  position: relative; 
}

#para2 {
  padding: 0px 1099px 0px 20px;
  position: relative; 
}

.username-label,
.password-label {
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 350px;
 position: relative; 
 top: -70px; 
}

.existingUsername, 
.existingPassword, 
#username_error1, 
#password_error2
{
    top: -70px; 
     position: relative;       
}

#button1{ 
     background-color: #add8e6;
     margin-left: 425px; 
     position: relative; 
     top: -70px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 
}

#button2{
  background-color: #add8e6;
  margin-left: -200px; 
  position: relative; 
  top: -30px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 

}


.Username-label1, 
.Password-label2,           
.Email-label3, 
.Repeat-Email-label4 
{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 330px;
  position: relative; 
  top: -70px; 
}
.newUsername, 
.newPassword, 
.newEmail, 
.repeatEmail{
  position: relative;
   top: -70px;
  margin-left: 40px; 

} 

span{

 color: red; 
 margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Project</title>

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">

    <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>

    <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row top">
      <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
      <div class="login">
        <label class="username-label" for="existingUsername">Username</label> 
         <input class="existingUsername" type="text" /><br><span id="username_error1"></span><br>


        <label class="password-label" for="existingPassword">Password</label>
        <input class="existingPassword" type="password"/><br><span id="password_error2"></span><br>
        <button id="button1">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row bottom">
      <p id="para2">New users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>

      <div class= "new_customers_info">

        <label class="Username-label1" for="newUsername">Username</label>
        <input class="newUsername" type="text"/><span id="New_Username_error"></span> 
        <span id="New_Username_error2"></span><br><br>

        <label class="Password-label2" for="newPassword">Password</label>
        <input class="newPassword" type="password"/ ><span id="New_Password_error"></span><br><br>

        <label class="Email-label3" for="newEmail">Email Address</label>
         <input class="newEmail" type="email" /><br><span id="New_Email_error"></span><br>

        <label class="Repeat-Email-label4" for="repeatEmail">Repeat Email Address</label>
         <input class="repeatEmail" type="email"/>
         <br><span id="NewReenter_Email_error"></span>
         <span id="NewReenter_Email_error2"></span>
        <button id="button2">Create Account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <br/>
  <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
  <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
</div>
    <script src="Home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello Everyone,

I want to use my validate function in order to output different errors messages within each of my current span id's. How can I do this, and if I can do this, what else do I need to accomplish this? Here is my code above.

Comment: After run your code snippet, there is an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Comment: @shaochuancs  Do you think you could help me? Is there a simpler way to do what I am asking to do?

Comment: Can you fix the syntax error and provide a minified, complete and verifiable code snippet?

Comment: @shaochuancs I having trouble with trying to understand the correct syntax of JQuery Plugin validation function. That's why I need help. I read online how it looks, but for some reason I can't apply it to my own situation.

Comment: @ shaochuancs  I tried to correct my code, but I don't know how I can get this validate function to working correctly. Any ideas? I just need help.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code within a

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code
});
```

Comment: I corrected my code but it's still giving me errors, how do I correct this.

Comment: @チャールズ-Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle for me to test, but...in the mean time

Are you sure validate takes a function directly ?

Isn't it just 
$('#button2').validate({ }); ?

Comment: @チャールズ-Are you still here online?

Comment: You have not included the jQuery validation plugin.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @ チャールズ How do I do that? Do I need to include a preloaded script in my <head> tags?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>  Is this the script tag I need to include the head tag?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js   use this one